# Importing class dynamically gives instantiation problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to import a class dynamically within a Vue js file. The class imports but I'm unable to instantiate it as I get this error in the browser console `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Franchise is not a constructor`

However, if I simply do a top-level import and try to instantiate it works. Could you please tell me what I'm oblivious of here?

Here's how the code looks:

```
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';


export default class Home extends Vue{
    franchiseComponent: any;

    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);
        const Franchise = require(`./../../franchises/MyFranchise`);
        
        const franchise = new Franchise();
        this.franchiseComponent = franchise.getHeader();
    }
```

The above code doesn't work and gives that error. But it works if I simply do a top level import.

And this is how the MyFranchise component looks:

```
import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
import { BaseFranchise } from "./../base/BaseFranchise";

export default class Franchise extends BaseFranchise {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  getHeader() {
    return Header;
  }
}
```

Comment: `import` is the standard ESM way to imoport files, while `require` is a NodeJS only thing. You can't `require` in JS, and where `require` is available, you can't `import` in NodeJS. The only way is to use a bundler that would inline that `require`, so that you'll gain nothing compared to a top level import. Alternatively, you can use dynamic `import('..')` but you need to be sure that path is correct.

Comment: `import a class dynamically` - what exactly are you trying to achieve?